# How can I validate select tag using angular validations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I want to add a message, whenever the user does not select any value in the select tag.
Until now I have approached as below:

```
    <form name="jdForm">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6 require">
                                <label class="form-control-label">Jd Name</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="jdname" ng-model="oData.jdDetails.jdName" required>
                                    <option>select</option>
                                    <option ng-repeat="jd in jdNames">{{jd}}</option>
                                </select>
                                <span ng-show="jdForm.jdname.$untouched ">Please select jd name</span>
                            </div>
<button ng-click="fnSave()">Publish</button>
</form>
```

Here the message is shown what I have given in span but the thing is onload event. It is showing but I need to show it after clicking on publish button. The ng-click function call should not happen until the form is validated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like:

```
savePressed && (jdForm.jdname.$untouched ||jdForm.jdname.$invalid)
```

Where savePressed is just a variable which turns to true after pressing the publish button.

See the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3EtZKx4TEI1K6OVN2lLx?p=preview) for a working copy

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer
but i need to get that message when i click on publish

Comment: I have changed the answer. It is the correct one now.

Answer (score 2):

you need to kept submit button instead simple ng-click and on every error message tag apply condition of is form submitted or if you want to show error even on focus out add one more condition of is touched.

bellow is example i  prefer for validating form

```
<span ng-messages="signupForm.password.$error" ng-if='signupForm.$submitted || signupForm.password.$touched'>
      <span ng-message="required" class="help-block">Please Enter password</span>
    </span>
```